# Testng- parallel execution not working :- When trying to run Selenium hybrid test in two browsers, test runs in only one browser

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, parallel-processing

When i launch the 2 browser, 2 browser is open successfully but only one browser working another browser not working

Need to execute parallel execution @ test and class level

The problem is when I run the test for two browsers
1)The first browser opens, navigates to the URL and then launch the application but not able to click the locator
2)The second browser not able to navigate the Url also

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.